# How to pick up a different file name depending on the date - google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've shown the first part of my script below. Each day a new data csv file will be dumped into the drive, for example todays would be called data@2020-19-03 and so on.. Is there a way I can have the script pick up the file for the day which the script is ran on? Hopefully that makes sense. At the moment I am having to manually change the date below before running the script.

```
var datafile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('data@2020-18-03').next();
var datacsv = Utilities.parseCsv(WIPfile.getBlob().getDataAsString());
datatab.getRange(1,1, datacsv.length, datacsv[0].length).setValues(datacsv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) to build the file name accordingly, using and formatting today's date.

Add this to your script:

```js
var date = "data@".concat(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "your-timeZone", "yyyy-dd-MM"));
```

#### Reference:

- [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))